# Why does R give me two outputs even though I am calculating a number?

Tags: r

Absolute R newbie here. I have been trying to make the following code calculate the population variance of an arbitrary argument called "values". For some reason, R spits out two values though.

```
u <- function(values) {
    tracker <- 0
    mid <- mean(values)
    for (i in values) {
        cuSum <- (i - mid)^2
        tracker <- tracker + cuSum
    }
    num <- range(values)
    return ((1/num)*tracker)
}
```

I tried the following driver code to check:
`print (u(c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)))`
Unfortunately, the output is `[1] 82.50  8.25`...but I want it to only be the latter.

I wish I could expand on what I have tried; unfortunately I have no idea how to even tackle this problem since this is the first piece of R code I have ever written. If someone could help me out here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `range(.)` returns two numbers; if you only want the second, use `max(values)` or `num[2]`. When you're in doubt of what a function does, see its help page; here, [`?range`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/range.html) says that it *"returns a vector containing the minimum and maximum of all the given arguments"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`range()` returns the smallest and largest values as a length-2 vector. If you want the magnitude of the range, use `diff(range(.))` instead.